# How can I make a QR-code containing a ~500 character URL as readable as possible?

Tags: url, qr-code, google-forms

TL;DR: long URL to a pre-filled google form is making the QR code difficult to scan, and seems to have problems with parsing.

I want to hand out printed QR codes containing a URL to a pre-filled google form. The URL therefore becomes long, about 500 characters (the URL is parsed so all non-ASCII characters are handled with %-codes). What can I do in order to make the QR code as readable as possible?

Currently I'm printing it as 8x8 cm, and it looks ok on the paper. My phone struggles to read it though, and sometimes it cannot interpret it as a URL, only as text.

I can see two problems in this project, and I suspect they combine.

1. The URL is too long in it self, making the browser not read it properly. This might be partly because the pre-filled form contains non-ASCII characters, which need to be parsed as %-codes. Still, the longest URL is 505 characters.
2. Even if the URL is working, the QR code needs to contain lots of information, making it very detailed and therefore difficult to scan.

Problem one I don't know how to address but if there are any rookie mistakes that are easy to commit, I'm sure to have done them and would love to have them pointed out!

Problem 2 seems as if I might want to look into the version of the QR code, and the error handling. But I don't know how to optimize it. The QR codes are generated in Python, using the [qrcode module](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/). As far as I can verify, it works for smaller codes (that is, shorter URLs).

Regarding workarounds: I don't want to create bitly-links or similar, since the URL contains personal information in clear text, and I don't want to store that on a server I don't control (yes, I understand I'm still giving the info to Google when using their forms). I would prefer all info from the register to be pre-filled in the form, so the members can correct mistakes or just press OK to confirm. I can send out the links (with pre-filled information) through e-mail, but a large part of the members will still need it on paper if we are to reach everyone.

What I've tried:

I have tried increasing the print quality, scanning with different apps, under different lights etc. I can sometimes get the phones to scan the codes correctly, but not reliably enough.

I have tried to not change non-ASCII characters to %-codes, which Google forms accepts -- but then the QR code didn't scan properly.

I have tried increasing the error handling in the QR code, which made it even larger, but the scanning was still a problem.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Increasing the error correction only improves robustness of a QR (how much you can destroy), at the cost of more squares. If you don't want a redirection service, you could look at other symbologies. I did a [small selection](https://imgur.com/a/Mdsi9FX), with a random string of 500 characters.

Comment: Other symbologies might be interesting, but have the drawback of being less recognizable. The recipients of the code vary wildly in tech savviness and willingness to participate.